# Is there a way to transfer persistent objects between OpenAccessContext

Tags: telerik, openaccess

Is there a way in telerik openaccess to copy an object from one OpenAccessContext to another?

I tried the following (ugly) approach: Take an object of one context, serialize it, deserialize and then put it in another context.

I cannot believe that there is no build in method to just clone an object. Does anyone know a better way? (and i do not mean: copy using reflection)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Attach / Detach](http://www.telerik.com/help/openaccess-orm/feature-ref-api-context-api-attach-detach.html) functionality of OpenAccess ORM to handle this scenario.

Comment: Functionality seems to be neither available in ObjectScope or IExtendedObjectScope?

Comment: You could use the scope methods: AttachCopies / CreateDetachedCopies.

Comment: You could contact the OpenAccess ORM support, in order to help you resolving the wrong behavior. http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/orm.aspx

Comment: Oh sorry, was a bit short: I tried the openaccess forum multiple times. The offered 2 solutions, which did not help at all (different error messages, mostly problems with linked objects, - only worked here for non linked objects...). In november we gave up using the build in things of OA. Now we use a generic object with a create method which recursivly creates a copy of an object in another objectscope, inherited from this object (~200 classes with sligh adjustments for linked objects) and this solution seems to work. Sadly the build in things were a waste of time for the project.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used the old ObjectContainer approach, available in the Classic API or the latest OpenAccessContext.CreateDetachedCopy + OpenAccessContext.AttachCopy functionality? I am wondering which one has caused the troubles